# RAII POSIX process created by fork

Tags: c++, c++11, linux, child-process, posix

By analogy with `std::thread`, I've written an RAII POSIX process:

```
class posix_process
{
public:
    explicit posix_process(std::function<void()> proc_main)
    : _pid(fork())
    {
        if (_pid == -1)
            throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), "fork");
        if (_pid == 0)
            proc_main();
    }

    pid_t pid() const
    {
        return _pid;
    }

    int wait(int options = 0) const
    {
        int wstatus = 0;
        const pid_t r = waitpid(_pid, &wstatus, options);
        if (r == -1)
            throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), "waitpid");
        return wstatus;
    }

private:
    // Disable copy and move
    posix_process(const posix_process&) = delete;
    posix_process(posix_process&&) = delete;
    posix_process& operator=(posix_process) = delete;

    pid_t _pid;
};
```

My main hesitation is that the child process ends up in a potentially weird state where the entire thing runs inside a constructor that was called in the parent process.

- Is this a good idea?
- What are the implications of making the class swappable by swapping `_pid` (and therefore, with minimal extra effort, moveable)?

Comment: Have you looked at [`boost::process::child`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost/process/child.html)?  You may be able to use that, or if not, to take inspiration from it.

Comment: @TobySpeight No, I haven't - thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Consider what happens after `proc_main()` finishes

> My main hesitation is that the child process ends up in a potentially weird state where the entire thing runs inside a constructor that was called in the parent process.

The problem is not so much calling `proc_main()` from a constructor, the problem is what happens after `proc_main()` finishes: the child process will continue to run, seemingly as if it was the parent, except `_pid` is now `0`. I think the expectation is that only `proc_main()` runs and then the process exits. Also consider that `proc_main()` might throw an exception. So it might be better to write:

```
if (_pid == 0) {
    try {
        proc_main();
    } catch(...) {
        std::abort();
    }
    std::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

## Make it look even more like `std::thread`

If you want something analogous to `std::thread`, go further and make the interface look like `std::thread` as much as possible. This makes it easier for someone who already knows `std::thread` to use your class. For one, instead of taking a `std::function<void()>` as a parameter, copy what `std::thread` does:

```
template <class Function, class... Args>
explicit posix_process(Function&& f, Args&&... args): _pid(fork())
{
    if (_pid == -1)
        throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), "fork");

    if (_pid == 0)
    {
        try {
            std::invoke(std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        } catch(...) {
            std::abort();
        }
        std::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

And rename `pid()` to `id()` and/or `native_handle()`.

## Make it moveable

> What are the implications of making the class swappable by swapping `_pid` (and therefore, with minimal extra effort, moveable)?

That would be very nice. This will allow `std::vector<posix_process>` and many other things that require the class to be at least moveable.

## Add a destructor

You might want to add a destructor that does something sensible rather than just letting a potential child process continue to run. `std::thread` will throw an exception if the thread is joinable and hasn't been joined yet, C++20's [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) will automatically join in its destructor, and that is usually preferred.

On the other hand, the semantics for a thread and a process are different, and it's much less dangerous to let a child process run without ever waiting for it, so if you have a good reason for it, I would probably accept not having a destructor.

Comment: Might be  a good idea to `std::exit()` (or perhaps even `std::_Exit()`) with the result of the function, if it returns something convertible to `int`.  And perhaps the `catch` should `std::abort()`, so that this is distinguishable by `WIFSIGNALED()`?  It's somewhat complicated by the state that's inherited across the `fork()`.

Comment: Good point. Although `std::thread`s don't have a return value, and a process can only return a small integer, so I don't think it makes much sense to do `std::exit(proc_main())`.

Comment: All excellent points - thank you. I hadn't considered what happens when `proc_main()` returns.

Answer (score 5):

## Construction and copying

I don't think we need to make this class non-moveable, but if we did, it's sufficient to delete just the copy constructor and assignment operator - we won't get compiler-generated move operations:

```
    // Disable copy and move
    posix_process(const posix_process&) = delete;
    void operator=(const posix_process&) = delete;
```

(Note that we can get away with declaring `void` return when we delete members).

As I said, I don't see any reason the class can't be moveable, so instead I'd write

```
    posix_process(posix_process&&) = default;
    posix_process& operator=(posix_process&&) = default;
```

Again, the presence of these declarations inhibits the compiler-provided copy operations, so we don't need any `=delete`.

## Increase the abstraction of `wait()`

The `wait()` function is an extremely thin veneer over the underlying `waitpid()`.  In particular, the `options` argument is not type-safe (consider defining an `enum class` for these, and accepting 0 or more of them as arguments instead).

Its return value is equally opaque - a raw exit status that calling code must unpack with macros such as `WIFEXITED()`.  Again, this could be more user-friendly - perhaps we should return a structure with this information already extracted ready for use?  At a minimum, enclose the raw value in a class with member functions to access these values.